# How to keep compiled files after starting a docker container with volume mounted?

Tags: css, docker, sass, docker-volume, docker-multi-stage-build

I have an image with multi-stage build for compiling some files and copy them into my final image.

I also set a volume between the directory of my app on the host machine and inside the container.

But when I start the container, the compiled files are not here. As I understand how volumes work, it makes perfect sense: the container replaces the content of his directory with the content of the directory on the host machine, where the compiled files are not generated as they are generated by the container when it is building.

But I am wondering if there is a way to keep the volume and have the compiled files in the container when it starts. I assume that I am doing it wrong.

To give you more info about my need, I want to compile `.css` files from `.scss` inside a nodejs image and I copy the compiled `.css` to `/app/<my_app>/static/css/` folder of my app docker image.

Here is my project's structure:

```
- docker-compose.yml
- production.env
- web/
- - Dockerfile
- - build/
- - - scss/
- - app/
- - - <my_app>/
- - - - static/
- - - - - css/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: web/
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file: 
      - ./production.env
    volumes:
      - ./web/app:/app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /build

COPY build/ .

RUN npm install && mkdir -p css

RUN npm run scss # Compile .scss files to .css into /build/css/ folder

FROM python:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY app/ .

COPY --from=builder /build/css ./<my_app>/static/css

/* ... Some instructions ... */

CMD flask run
```

Here, when I build the container the css files do not exist yet, they are compiled, copied to the final image. When I start the image, as there is a volume between ./web/app:/app, the content of the image is replaced with the content in the host machine and so the .css files are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution by myself, so I post the answer here hoping it will help someone else.

I abandoned the multi-stage build and try to create an image dedicated to scss compiling.

Here is the `Dockerfile` of this image:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /build

COPY package.json ./

RUN mkdir -p ./scss ./css

RUN npm install

CMD npm run scss
```

Note that I use the module node-sass for compiling scss in a nodejs environment.

For now, it just compiles files from `scss/` and puts the output into `css/`. But there is nothing in those folders yet.

I edit my `docker-compose.yml` to run this new image at start and set two volumes from static folders of my app to `scss/` and `css/` folder in the container of this new image called `scss`. So when `web` will start, `static/css` will be filled by this new service using files from `static/scss` as source.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: web/
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - scss
    env_file: 
      - ./production.env
    volumes:
      - ./web/app:/app
  scss:
    build: scss/
    env_file:
      - ./production.env
    volumes:
      - ./web/app/<my_app>/static/css:/build/css
      - ./web/app/<my_app>/static/scss:/build/scss
```

Finally, it works.

After running `$ docker-compose up -d`, css files are here. The container of `scss` image is not running as it is a one-shot command, not a proper service running, but you can run it again if you made some changes to your `.scss` files and you want to compile `.css` again.